# Button play/pause youtube embed video

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

JS (This is a Youtube Api Code)

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
          videoId: 'nYSDC3cHoZs',
          playerVars: {
            'showinfo': 0
        },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
            'autoplay':true
          }
        });


    document.getElementById('pause').onclick = function p() {
        player.pauseVideo();
         pausebtn.src = "img/play.ico";
         return true;
    };

    document.getElementById('resume').onclick = function r() {
        player.playVideo();
         pausebtn.src = "img/pause.ico";
         return true;
    };

      }
```

In the HTML I have this icon

```
<a href="#" id="pause"><img id='pausebtn' src="img/pause.ico"></a>
```

I want to changue the pause icon to play icon when I stop the video and when appears the play video icon this call to a resume function.

Any Idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`pausebtn.src` *pausebtn* is not defined.
Use `this.src` istead.

`getElementById('resume')` where's your `#resume` in your HTML? As far as I can tell it's the *same* `#pause` one.

**Instead of:**

```js
document.getElementById('pause').onclick = function p() {
  player.pauseVideo();
  pausebtn.src = "img/play.ico";
  return true;
};

document.getElementById('resume').onclick = function r() {
  player.playVideo();
  pausebtn.src = "img/pause.ico";
  return true;
};
```

**try with:**

```js
const pauseBtn = document.querySelector("#pausebtn");

pauseBtn.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const tog = this.dataset.tog ^= 1;
  this.src = tog ? "img/play.ico" : "img/pause.ico";
  player[tog ? "pauseVideo" : "playVideo"]();
});
```

where you store a `0/1` inside the Element's [data attribute by using Element.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). In order to switch the 0/1 you can use the [Bitwise XOR assignment `^=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR_assignment).

Then use a [ternary operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to change the `src` value depending on that `tog` 0/1 value evaluated as boolean. Finally, call a function, again in respect to the current `tog` state (in `player[tog ? "pauseVideo" : "playVideo"]()`), which, to recap, is just a shorthand for `if (tog /* is 1 */) { pauseVideo(); } else { playVideo(); }`

Comment: Some explanation of the code would have been very helpful.